# MemoryError: unable to allocate 53.5Mib for an arraray

Tags: python, manejo-de-memoria, test, validación, memoria

Escribo este codigo

```
'import pandas as pd
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 from sklearn import linear_model
 from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

 data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/base_datos_2008.csv')

 df = data.dropna(subset = ["ArrDelay"])
 df = df.sample(frac=1).head(1000)

 X = df[['AirTime', 'Distance', 'DepDelay']]
 Y = df['ArrDelay']

 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split("X,Y", test_size = .2, random_state = 10)

 regrINTERNA = linear_model.LinearRegression()
 regrINTERNA.fit(X, Y)
 prediccionesINTERNA = regrINTERNA.predict(X)
 print("R2: ", r2_score(Y, prediccionesINTERNA))'
```

y me aparece le siguiente error:
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 53.5 MiB for an array with shape (7009728,) and data type int64

tengo una i7 con 16 gb de ram y un tera de disco duro. en otro post vi que se pod[ia almacenar la memoria en el disco duro en lugar de la RAM para evitar quemarla. ¿cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Tienes que cambiar de metodología. No es un problema de hardware. La RAM no se quema ni con los videos más ardientes de Internet. Puedes sacarse esa preocupación de encima.

Comment: A mi me ocurre cuando hay un bucle infinito, por si te sirve...

Comment: Te sirve [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)?

Comment: Hola, Cuando digo que quema es que consuma toda la memoria ram disponible. Pero lo que quiero saber es como resolverlo y que pueda ejecutar el codigo que le indique.

Comment: perdón, no entiendo qué me sirve? Srsole

Comment: Bueno,les comento, al parecer la solución era descargar la version de 64 bits ya que estaba usando la versión de 32 bits. Ejecuté el código y no me salió ningun error solo que me dice que no hay valores suficientes para desempacar [valueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)